# PrimeNG data table not displaying in angular 2

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to display a basic data table but cannot seem to get it working even though I've read through the documentation. I am not getting any console errors, the table just does not display. I am able to get some of the other prime ng components to work so I assume there is nothing wrong with my setup.

I have an array declared in my component that looks like this:

```
this.employees = [
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}
];
```

In my template I have this:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="employees">
    <p-column field="firstName" header="First Name"></p-column>
    <p-column field="lastName" header="Last Name"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Perhaps I have misunderstood the documentation and there is something wrong with either my array or my template? Thanks

Comment: this error is with your version... I change to "primeng": "4.0.0", and remove ^ ... after this my code works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I just forgot to add the DataTable and Column directives to the component. It works fine after including them

Comment: Hi Mark,  I am having similar issue. Could you post your solution please as it is not working for me

Comment: import {DataTable} from 'primeng/primeng';

Comment: @Component({
 ...
  directives: [DataTable]
})

Comment: I don't know if that will be much help but in my case it was just that I left out the DataTable directives part

Comment: Or in newer versions of Angular2 ( > RC6 ) you should declare them at @NgModule({imports : [DataTable , Column] }) in your app.module.ts

Comment: It is now: import { DataTableModule } from 'primeng/components/datatable/datatable';

Comment: And update the directive name in app.module.ts NgModule too import section